# Populating TreeMap<String, ArrayList(of different lengths) > with <ArrayList> data

Tags: java, arraylist, treemap

My function takes in a Scanner and returns a TreeMap `map` with Strings as keys, and an ArrayList as a value. These ArrayLists can be of different lengths. I've parsed the Scanner to a new ArrayList `textData` for easier iteration. The procedure should go as follows:

1. If the element is a String, have that be the new key to the next TreeMap entry (stored as `String state`) and clear the temporary array
2. If the element is parseable to a Double, add it to the temporary ArrayList `statePopData`.
3. Commit to `map`.

Ideally, with the scanner :

`"Utah\t6.0\t60\n"
+ "California\t5\t30\n"
+ "Nevada\t3"`

should return:

`{"Utah",[6.0, 60.0], "California",[5.0, 30.0], "Nevada",[3.0],}`

Here is what I have thus far:

```
 public static TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Double>> readTable (Scanner dataSource)
{
        //Parse Scanner to ArrayList
    ArrayList<String> textData = new ArrayList<String>();

    while(dataSource.hasNext()){
        textData.add(dataSource.next());
   }

    //Populate TreeMap
    ArrayList<Double> statePopData = new ArrayList<>();
    TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Double>> map = new TreeMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < textData.size(); i++) {

        boolean isDouble;
        String state = "";


      try {
          Double.parseDouble(textData.get(i));
          isDouble = true;
      } catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException nfe) {
          isDouble = false;
      }


      if(isDouble) {
          statePopData.add(Double.parseDouble(textData.get(i)));
      } else { //means its a string

          statePopData.clear();
          state = textData.get(i);
      } 

      if (statePopData.isEmpty()) {
          map.put(state, statePopData);
      }

    } return map;}
```

I feel confident with the pieces, but I can never seem to run the `map.put()` statement at the right time with the proper values to commit. For example, my current results of the program are: `{California=[3.0], Nevada=[3.0], Utah=[3.0]}`

EDIT: The linked answer doesn't involve any implementation nor fully answers what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @mentallurg I am still learning :D

Comment: This is the right moment to start using debugger.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed test case, what am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58195283/failed-test-case-what-am-i-doing-wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like duplicate code to [Failed test case, what am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58195283/failed-test-case-what-am-i-doing-wrong/58195614)
The same `ArrayList` instance is being modified and set for each state, so it is being cleared and overwritten each time. A simpler approach may be:

```
    TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Double>> map = new TreeMap<>();
    while (dataSource.hasNext()) {
        String state = dataSource.next();
        Double d = Double.parseDouble(dataSource.next());
        map.computeIfAbsent(state, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(d);
    }
    return map;
```

**Updated solution for state followed by multiple numbers:**

```
// Usually better to use List than ArrayList for declared generic types
public static TreeMap<String, List<Double>> readTable(Scanner dataSource) {
    TreeMap<String, List<Double>> map = new TreeMap<>();
    String state = null;
    while (dataSource.hasNext()) {
        String next = dataSource.next(); // Should never be null
        try {
            Double d = Double.parseDouble(next);
            // Ignores numbers received before state is set
            if (state != null)
                // If state has been set, list that must have been initialized
                map.get(state).add(d); 
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // Assumes any non-double is a state
            state = next;
            // Initialize map entry with empty list
            map.put(state, new ArrayList<>());
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: I'm struggling to implement this... Where do I fit this in the larger code/vise versa?

Comment: This would be a replacement for the contents of the method `readTable`. It uses the Scanner dataSource directly, rather than reading into an array first. And it assumes there is always a state value followed by a number. I'll update for the case of multiple numbers.

Comment: Done - see above.