# Failed test case, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, arrays, treemap

I've been trying to get this to work, but I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong. It'll make sense with the test case in a bit. Some things about what I'm doing. The list must have one or more lines. If there's not at least one line,  an IllegalArgumentException is thrown. Each line has some kind of String, then a tab character, then a double, then a newline. If any lines don't follow this pattern, then an IllegalArgumentException would also be thrown. This is ideally supposed to work if you made any number of lists, so that's why I attempted it this way

Basically, the program is supposed to get a list, say something like...

```
California   6
Nevada      11
California   1
California  14
Arizona     21
Utah         2
California   7
Utah        10
Nevada       3
Utah         2
```

and should return something like this:

```
California {6, 1, 14, 7} 
Arizona    {21}
Utah       {2, 10, 2}
Nevada     {11, 3}
```

Note that I only used four for the sake of the example. I'm trying to get it so that it's work with any number of lists.
Here is my code...

```
 public static TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Double>> readTable (Scanner dataSource)
    {

        ArrayList<String> dataFromFile = new ArrayList<String>();

        while(dataSource.hasNext()){
            dataFromFile.add(dataSource.next());
       }

        //Populate TreeMap
        ArrayList<Double> statePopData = new ArrayList<>();
        TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Double>> map = new TreeMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < dataFromFile.size(); i++) {

            boolean isDouble;
            String state = "";


          try {
              Double.parseDouble(dataFromFile.get(i));
              isDouble = true;
          } catch (NumberFormatException | NullPointerException nfe) {
              isDouble = false;
          }


          if(isDouble) {
              statePopData.add(Double.parseDouble(dataFromFile.get(i)));
          } else { //means its a string

              statePopData.clear();
              state = dataFromFile.get(i);
          } 
          if (statePopData.isEmpty()) {
              map.put(state, statePopData);
          }

        } return map;
}
```

I keep getting one same value for everything for all the other states in the list and I'm confused as to why this is happening.

Here's the test case I mentioned before...

```
@Test
    public void testReadTable ()
    {
        try (Scanner scn = new Scanner(
                "Utah\t10\nNevada\t3\nUtah\t2\nCalifornia\t14\nArizona\t21\nUtah\t2\nCalifornia\t7\nCalifornia\t6\nNevada\t11\nCalifornia\t1\n"))
        {
            TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Double>> actual = GraphingMethods.readTable(scn);

            TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Double>> expected = new TreeMap<>();
            ArrayList<Double> azList = new ArrayList<>();
            azList.add(21.0);
            expected.put("Arizona", azList);

            ArrayList<Double> caList = new ArrayList<>();
            caList.add(6.0);
            caList.add(1.0);
            caList.add(14.0);
            caList.add(7.0);
            expected.put("California", caList); 

            ArrayList<Double> nvList = new ArrayList<>();
            nvList.add(11.0);
            nvList.add(3.0);
            expected.put("Nevada", nvList);     

            ArrayList<Double> utList = new ArrayList<>();
            utList.add(2.0);
            utList.add(10.0);
            utList.add(2.0);
            expected.put("Utah", utList);

            assertEquals(expected, actual);
        }
    }
```

I'm a new programmer, so any advice would be greatly appreciated! I'd love to know what I'm doing wrong so that I can learn more. :)

Comment: This part looks suspicious to me - `if (statePopData.isEmpty()) {  map.put(state, statePopData` - should that be `if (!statePopData.isEmpty())` perhaps?

Comment: @Dawidd It didn't seem to change the outcome much. But what you said makes me think that maybe the if statements are the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem is you are modifying and inserting the same `ArrayList` instance for each state. A simple version, without robustness checking might be:

```
    TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Double>> map = new TreeMap<>();
    while (dataSource.hasNext()) {
        String state = dataSource.next();
        Double d = Double.parseDouble(dataSource.next());
        map.computeIfAbsent(state, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(d);
    }
    return map;
```

The `computeIfAbsent` allows you to add a new `ArrayList` when you see a new state (Java 8+).

Another issue is the `assertEquals`. Since the expected number list data is in a different order than the actual, the `ArrayLists` are not equal. You could verify the keys and values like this:

```
    assertEquals(expected.keySet(), actual.keySet());
    expected.forEach((state, list) -> {
        Collections.sort(list);
        Collections.sort(actual.get(state));
        assertEquals(list, actual.get(state));
    });
```

Comment: There's a few things here that I haven't quite learned yet. What does  ```map.computeIfAbsent(state, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(d);``` mean? I kinda get the gist of it, though.

Comment: It's a lambda expression in Java 8. Basically if the key doesn't exist, then add a new key with the state and an empty Arraylist and add the double to the list.

Comment: And the `expected.forEach` is a nicer way to iterate maps without having to directly reference `Map.Entry`

Answer (score 0):

Your code clears statePopData every time there is a new string, so even if you see:

```
California 1
California 2
California 3
```

You will only wind up with a map that says California: 3, as map.put() will replace the current value for the key "California" with whatever you provide it.

You need to recall the current version of the state's array each time you see that state, and then append the new data to the array before you re-insert that .

Comment: This helped a lot! Now I'm not getting repeat values, but now all the values in the entire list are being assigned to each state. I'll try to mess with it, hopefully I can figure it out a bit more...

Comment: ```else
            {

                state = dataFromFile.get(i);
                map.put(state, statePopData);
            }```  These are the changes that I made so far.

Comment: For each item, you need to pull the array for the specific state back out of the map, then append the new value, then put that new array back into the map.  You can't just maintain the same array for all states.

Comment: Interesting, let me try this out :)

Comment: This is wrong. Based on the code, it will never enter the "else" clause

Comment: @robsie Sorry, I'm still a little confused. I just need to make it so that a new array list is made for each different item on the list?

Comment: You need a separate array for each state on the list.  Using the map to hold each state as you build it is good -- but you need to recall that array out of the map to append to it each time you see the state again, otherwise you will just wind up with a single item in the list.


One thing that is a bit confusing in your code is that you seem to be deciding what to do based on if there is a number or not -- but the format of the test reliably produces word then number.  _If_ you can rely on that, consider assuming a number following each word.

Comment: @Shady Am I over-complicating the code? I seem to do that whenever I have a problem...

Comment: @robsie Thanks! I'll keep trying this. I'm doing that because part of this project is learning how to throw stuff when I get a bad list or something like that. I'm going to make other test cases in the future that test stuff like that later on.